# cant get value from dropdown list(kedo drop down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I m a newbie on jquery UI. Can you please tell why

```
$('#ddlPanel').data("kendoDropDownList").select($("#ddlPanel")[0].selectedIndex);
```

Didn't fetch me value after a post back.

I will make that simple. on selecting any value from dropdown, the value should be retained after onclick.

I have tried the above one but results with an undefined value.

`<select id="ddlPanel"> <option value="0">Select Business Unit</option> . . </select>`

This is from .cshtml `$('#ddlPanel').data("kendoDropDownList").select($("#ddlPanel")[0].selectedIndex)‌​;`

And i used the above jquery to retain the value after postback

Answer (score 1):

You can do `$("#ddlPanel").data("kendoDropDownList").text();` or `$('#ddlPanel').data("kendoDropDownList").value();` to get value from DropDownList..
You can refer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/Nq7Mf/92/)

Comment: after using this i can get the text and value. But on post back the index value changes to '0' and the text in the drop down is 'Select'

Comment: <select id="ddlPanel">
  <option value="0">Select Business Unit</option>
   .
   .
</select>
This is from .cshtml
$('#ddlPanel').data("kendoDropDownList").select($("#ddlPanel")[0].selectedIndex);

And i used the above jquery to retain the value after postback

Comment: After u get the value then you can set by `$("#ddlPanel").data("kendoDropDownList").value("your value");`

Comment: check my updated fiddle..Onclick of button I set it to another value..if you know the index then u can use `select()` otherwise use `value("your value")` to set after post back..

Comment: Thanks debin that fetches me the value. But once on click pagepost backs and the value behind it reverts again to select business.

Comment: yeah because by default it will set to `selected` option or first option that's why it select `select business`..

Comment: If u want to set selected value onload then use `cookie` or `session` to save the value and use it on refresh or postback